# Angular JS ng-switch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.3, ng-switch, angularjs-ng-switch

I am developing an application with Laravel and Angular JS.
I am using [[ ]] for data binding.

On binding data in table with ng-switch is getting error and not working.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <td>[[category.Name]]</td>
            <td>[[category.ListOrder]]</td>
            <td ng-switch="category.Status">
              <img ng-switch-when="1" src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/images/icons/ic_active.png')}}"></td>
              <img ng-switch-when="0" src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/images/icons/ic_inactive.png')}}"></td>
            <td>
              <img src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/images/icons/ic_inactive.png')}}">
            </td>
            <td>[[category.updated_at]]</td>
</tr>
```

The response Status variable getting string values 1 and 0 when I check with Firebug.

How can I solve this....

I am using Angular JS v1.5.8

Error in Console..

```
 Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngSwitch&p1=ngSwitchWhenN/<@http://localhost/repos/p3-laravel/ppp_admin/public/js/angular.min.js:6:412
```

Comment: *"is getting error and not working"* – can you put that in more concrete terms? What's the error message, what is happening, what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @deceze  edited question with console error.

Comment: @JpDevs can you use the unminified version of AngularJS? it seems you're using the minified version

Comment: @K3v1n Now I  check with unminified cdn and now showning error like Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!

Comment: @JpDevs it doesn't seem to be finding the parent ng-switch

Comment: How can I Solve it

Comment: use ng-src not src. that is not solving the problem. can you test your code on chrome ? because when you get an error, you can click on the error in the console and it open an explanation on angular web site

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngSwitch&p1=ngSwitchWhen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td ng-switch="category.Status">
    <img ng-switch-when="1" ...></td>
    <img ng-switch-when="0" ...></td>
```

You're prematurely closing closing the `</td>` after the first `img`, the second `img` is outside the `<td>` and thereby also outside the scope of `ng-switch`. The error is caused by `ng-switch-when="0"` not being able to find a parent `ng-switch`.

Comment: Thanks for notice dude.  Two hours spend on this.

Comment: FWIW, proper HTML formatting could have easily prevented this (`</td>` not on the same line, and keeping your lines shorter).